# Why Can't Ionic Find My Model Interface?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and am loosely following [this tutorial](https://blog.paulhalliday.io/2017/09/08/ionic-3-and-firebase-user-authentication/) to add firebase authentication to my project. I am having an issue with the user interface that is created.

On the initial `ionic serve`

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find module '../../models/user'.
D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/pages/login/login.ts
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { User } from "../../models/user";
```

**If I save any of the project files, and force the app to rebuild, the error disappears. It only happens on the initial serve.**

I have tried changing the path to `../shared/models/user` to no avail.

My `user.ts` file is located at `src/shared/models/user.ts`.

My import statement in login.ts: `import { User } from "../../models/user";`

User class:

```
export interface User {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/pages/login/` + `../../models/user` = `D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/models/user`

`D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/pages/login/` + `../shared/models/user` = `D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/pages/shared/models/user`

Whats about `../../shared/models/user` ?

`D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/pages/login/` + `../../shared/models/user` = `D:/Ionic/pigsnbulls/pigsnbulls/src/shared/modesl/user`